# iOS7.1: is it possible to record multiple built-in microphones?

Tags: ios, audio

iPhone 5 has 3 microphones. Is it possible to record all of them simultaneously using AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute? I see all of them when listing inputDataSources from current session, but have no idea how to select several of them?